# Null and Undefined check in Typescript - Angular Forms

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this huge check in Form values of Angular Application and I need to refactor.

```
((this.dropdownSearchForm.get('name').value === undefined || this.dropdownSearchForm.get('name').value === null || this.dropdownSearchForm.get('name').value.length === 0) &&
    (this.dropdownSearchForm.get('status').value === undefined || this.dropdownSearchForm.get('status').value === null || this.dropdownSearchForm.get('status').value.length === 0) &&
    (this.dropdownSearchForm.get('address').value === undefined || this.dropdownSearchForm.get('address').value === null || this.dropdownSearchForm.get('address').value.length === 0) &&
    (this.dropdownSearchForm.get('edu').value === undefined || this.dropdownSearchForm.get('edu').value === null || this.dropdownSearchForm.get('edu').value.length === 0) &&
    (this.dropdownSearchForm.get('salary').value === undefined || this.dropdownSearchForm.get('salary').value === null || this.dropdownSearchForm.get('salary').value.length === 0));
```

How can I simplify this with Typescript utils to achieve the same result with minimum code?

Note: Angular forms touch or pristine doesn't work. So checking this logic to validate form values.

I tried checking type of and it didn't work for some reason.

Comment: "Note: Angular forms touch or pristine doesn't work." - Can you explain?
Truthy / Falsy values might help. [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)

Comment: Any time you are acting with a HTML form control you have the possibility of the value not being there unless there is a default. In short, there is no way to statically verify something like user input that can't possibly be known until runtime. That being said, HTML forms have validators built in, I'm not an angular dev but that code looks pretty sus to me.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you're checking that the value of each form is either `undefined`, `null`, or `0`.

Your conditional appears to be verifying that each control includes one of these values.

Since the values are all falsy, I think you could do this...

```
checkEm() {
  const vals = [
        this.dropdownSearchForm.get('name').value,
        this.dropdownSearchForm.get('status').value,
        this.dropdownSearchForm.get('address').value,
        this.dropdownSearchForm.get('edu').value,
        this.dropdownSearchForm.get('salary').value,
    ]
    // Make sure every value is falsy (!{falsy_value} = true):
    return vals.every(val => !val)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something similar to this:

```
 this.myForm = fb.group({
        field1: [null],
        field2: [null]
        // more fields 
    }, {validator: this.myValidator})
```

Then in your validator iterate the formcontrols in your group, sum up and return error or null based on valid or not:

```
 myValidator(group: FormGroup) {
      let sum = 0;
      for(let a in group.controls) {
        sum += group.get([a]).value;
      }
      return sum > 10 ? { notValid: true} : null
    }
```

and in the template you can display error with:`enter code here`

```
*ngIf="myForm.hasError('notValid')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Based off of [Tanner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74465381/12101554), you can just pass in the keys themselves and have the loop handle the `this.dropdownSearchFor.get(...).value` part.

```
checkEm() {
  const vals = [
        'name',
        'status',
        'address',
        'edu',
        'salary'
    ]
    // Make sure every value is falsy (!{falsy_value} === true):
    return vals.every(val => !this.dropdownSearchForm.get(val));
}
```

based on the content of the question, it seems like your original code might be wrong, since it looks like you want to make sure every value is truthy

that code would look like this:

```
checkEm() {
  const vals = [
        'name',
        'status',
        'address',
        'edu',
        'salary'
    ]
    // Make sure every value is truthy:
    return vals.every(val => this.dropdownSearchForm.get(val));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this code snippet:

```
(!this.dropdownSearchForm.get('name').value &&
!this.dropdownSearchForm.get('status').value &&
!this.dropdownSearchForm.get('address').value &&
!this.dropdownSearchForm.get('edu').value &&
!this.dropdownSearchForm.get('salary').value);
```